# Tensorflow: How to initialize variables on another graph?

Tags: tensorflow

I have a default graph and a newly created graph (G1).

In G1, I have a variable named "a".

I can use `tf.import_graph_def` to include G1 onto the main graph, and expose its "a" variable.

**How do I initialize this variable and successfully print the value of "a" ?**

Here is the actual code:

```
import tensorflow as tf

INT = tf.int32


def graph():
    g = tf.Graph()
    with g.as_default() as g:
        a = tf.get_variable('a', [], INT, tf.constant_initializer(10))
    return g


tf.reset_default_graph()

g = graph()
[g_a] = tf.import_graph_def(g.as_graph_def(), return_elements=['a:0'])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print(sess.run(g_a))
```

The above won't work, it will error with `FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value import/a`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason you get errors is that when you import a graph def, no variables and values are imported or restored.

You can use variables in another graph if you do the following:

- declare your variable in a session, then run tf.global_variables_initalizer()
- save your variable
- after you import your graph_def, restore your variable
- **important**: when you  import the graph def use name='' to use the same namespace as in your other graph otherwise you get errors

A minimal example how to to this:

```
import tensorflow as tf

INT = tf.int32

def graph():
    g = tf.Graph()
    with tf.Session(graph=g) as sess:
        a = tf.get_variable("a", shape=[1], dtype=INT, initializer=tf.constant_initializer(10))
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        saver = tf.train.Saver()
        saver.save(sess, './test_dir/test_save.ckpt')
        return g


g = graph()

tf.reset_default_graph()

g_a = tf.import_graph_def(g.as_graph_def(), return_elements=['a:0'], name='')

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    second_saver = tf.train.Saver(var_list=g_a)
    second_saver.restore(sess, './test_dir/test_save.ckpt')
    a = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0')
    print(sess.run(a))
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need is detailed in tensorflow documentation here :

https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/saved_model

See this part with associates code example :

> Choosing which variables to save and restore

If you do not pass any arguments to tf.train.Saver(), the saver handles all variables in the graph. Each variable is saved under the name that was passed when the variable was created.

It is sometimes useful to explicitly specify names for variables in the checkpoint files. For example, you may have trained a model with a variable named "weights" whose value you want to restore into a variable named "params".

It is also sometimes useful to only save or restore a subset of the variables used by a model. For example, you may have trained a neural net with five layers, and you now want to train a new model with six layers that reuses the existing weights of the five trained layers. You can use the saver to restore the weights of just the first five layers.

You can easily specify the names and variables to save or load by passing to the tf.train.Saver() constructor either of the following:

- A list of variables (which will be stored under their own names).
- A Python dictionary in which keys are the names to use and the values are the variables to manage

Comment: I dug into your source .. I didn't find it useful. One thing is I don't work with Saver() right now. I just created a graph imported to the default graph and just tried to initialize its variables. As far as I understand, variables initialization must be done in "session" if not predefined somewhere else. About which, I have found no way to do it.

Comment: After I came back to this. I realized that it is by design that graphs are separated. It is likely that saving and restoring is the only way to connect them. Thanks.